# SSD split into two drives

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

I recently installed a 250GB SSD. I copied my Windows C drive over to my SSD F drive.
The computer now boots to the F drive SSD but my SSD seems to be split up as my F drive is showing it has 149gb storage and I have a new D drive with 77GB storage on it.

How do I combine the disks together?

See images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Given the way the disk partitions is allocated you don't.  You need to reimage the ssd, so the recovery partition, is before the C partition.

Comment: Do you know how I could do that? Thanks